# Having trouble with NSSound currentTime

Tags: cocoa, ime, nssound

I'm using NSSound and I can get sounds to play / pause correctly, but for some reason I can't get the currentTime method to return anything else than zero.

Here's the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
NSSound* sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"path_to_sound.mp3" byReference:NO];
[sound play];
sleep(1);
NSLog(@"Current time: %f", [sound currentTime]);
```

The sound plays but the NSLog always returns zero. Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out it works on my internal speakers, but stops working as soon as I plug in my firewire audio interface. Any idea why this function doesn't work anymore with an external audio interface? Anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

`NSSound` uses the default sound device, by default. you can change output device using `setPlaybackDeviceIdentifier:` method of [NSSound](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/NSSound_Class.pdf) class.
Take a look at [this](http://fdiv.net/2008/08/12/nssound-setplaybackdeviceidentifier-coreaudio-output-device-enumeration) and [how to get Audio Device UID to pass into NSSound's setPlaybackDeviceIdentifier:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983984/how-to-get-audio-device-uid-to-pass-into-nssounds-setplaybackdeviceidentifier) for getting unique identifier of a sound output device

Comment: When I have my external audio interface plugged in the sound does play on the external interface, as it becomes the default device. Play / pause / resume all work as they should, but the currentTime method returns 0. So my problem is not to select the correct interface, it's just that the currentTime method stops working on the external interface. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up switching to QTMovie instead of NSSound. The currentTime of that one works with my audio interface. As for NSSound and why its currentTime doesn't work with my audio interface, that remains a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a machine to test things, but I expect that you may learn what you need from:

```
NSLog(@"Playback on %@, current time: %@ / %@",
   [sound playbackDeviceIdentifier], [sound currentTime], [sound duration]);
```

Comment: On the internal speakers I get:
    2012-07-24 01:46:34.905 Untitled[4961:a0f] Playback on (null), current time: 1.044898 / 376.440000

And when I plug in the audio interface:
    2012-07-24 01:47:26.664 Untitled[4978:a0f] Playback on (null), current time: 0.000000 / 376.440000. As I mentioned earlier, the currentTime method stops working.

Comment: Strange that you get *null* as the device, in both cases... What happens if you NSLog(@"sound: %@",sound)? Something else: it's been suggested that *sleep()* does not work well with the currentTime method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280453/nssound-not-working-properly?rq=1), what happens if you delete the sleep statement?

Comment: When I NSLog the sound I get: "sound: <NSSound: 0x100543eb0>", so that looks fine. Sound is playing through my external interface, as I said it's only the currentTime method that returns 0. I tried removing sleep and putting the NSLog inside another method triggered by a timer and it still returns 0 all the time.

Comment: Very strange, I cannot think of an explanation. Since it does work for @Parag Bafna, it is possible that something is wrong in your development environment, or with the inclusion. Long shot, but are you using the most recent xcode (and OSX>=10.5), and properly including?